# How to show small picture (or icon) in front of text?

Tags: graphics

How to show small pictures in front of text in Latex similar to what is made by Microsoft Word as depicted in the following image?

[image]

The result obtained via `\includegraphics` is not satisfactory and is as follows:

[image]

Comment: @campa , I changed the image. The purpose is to put a small image in front of text, so that the small image is inserted in a line.

Comment: Not sure if this is what you want but maybe it could help https://tikz.dev/tikz-transparency

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To include an image in the middle of text, use `\includegraphics` from graphicx. If the image is not of a suitable size you can resize it like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
Here is an image: \includegraphics[height=1ex]{example-image-a}.
\end{document}
```

It may look better to lower the image a bit. You can use `\raisebox` (with a negative argument) for that, for example like:

```
A bit bigger: \raisebox{-.2ex}{\includegraphics[height=2ex]{example-image-a}}.
```